# Can/Should the main component be the only component with a state in react JS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a react app that ties into localStorage of the browser. On the startup of the app, the localStorage is populated with all the data that is needed to run the app. This data is pulled with AJAX from XML files and constructed to form a localStorageObject that the web app can use as its "database" of information to pull content from...

At the moment, The main component's state is set to the localstorage. So essentially I have the following:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      courseData : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("storageID"));,

    }
  }
```

The state contains an object that is the entirety of the localStorage. Now I have many children components, who also have children components themselves. Some are components that just need to render once, while others are going to need to rerender with interaction from the user.

After reading, it seems there are many ways to implement a solution. I could have all the components have state, but that's not needed. I could just have the main component have state, and no other component have state. And whenever the state of the main component changes, the props will be based down and reupdated.

Is there a specific method that is best?

Answer (score 0):

This method works, but.

First of all, `localStorage` calls should be on a `componentDidMount` function. Otherwise, it wouldn't work on a server-side-rendering case.

Secondly, I'd implement all the initial data fetching on a parent function and then pass down data to the root of react tree:

```
const localStorageData = localStorage.getItem('some_data')

ReactDom.render(
  document.getElementById('my-element'),
  <MyComponent
     localStorageData={localStorageData}
   />
)
```

Comment: My one issue now is that if these components are rendered solely based on props, and the parent state changes, then the children wont update as well. Since props are set on first render, and don't update even if "new props" are sent through

Answer (score 0):

if have many children components it will be difficult to manage state because of deep nesting.
I would recommend using Higher Order Component for your local storage implementation And Pass it down to children. Here How I would do it:

```
 import React from 'react';
var HigherOrderComponent = (Component) =>
  class  extends React.Component {

    state={locStorage:{}}

    componentDidMount(){

        this.setState({locStorage:window.localStorage.getItem("data")})
      }


    render() {
      return (
        <Component
            locStorage={this.state.locStorage}
        />
      )
    }
  };

export default HigherOrderComponent;


import HigherOrderComponent  from './HigherOrderComponent'
const ChildComponent = ({locStorage}) => {
    console.log(locStorage)
    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    );
};

export default HigherOrderComponent(ChildComponent);
```